# Pointing Cloudflare CNAME to AWS ALB results in Error 522

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloudflare

Setting up DNS on Cloudflare to point to an ALB on AWS. It seems when I make a CNAME record pointing to the DNS name of the ALB it fails with a 522 error.

When I do an nslookup on the DNS name of the load balancer, and change the records to A records with one of the IPs, everything works as expected. This solution is not going to work, since 1) I'm not taking advantage of the load balancing aspect of the DNS name, and 2) the IPs of the load balancer can change at any moment.

The load balancer has the same SSL certs as Cloudflare, and is using listeners with the host as the condition.

For example: test.domain.com forwards to one target group, and test2.domain.com forwards to a different target group.

Is there something I am missing with this kind of setup? Why would it be working when using an IP address, but not with the CNAME?

Update: Including example listener setup in Terraform:

```
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "nginx" {
  listener_arn = "${var.https_listener_arn}"
  priority     = 1

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = "${aws_lb_target_group.nginx.arn}"
  }

  condition {
    field  = "host-header"
    values = ["${var.frontend_host}"]
  }
}
```

Comment: You mentioned changing to *one of* the balancer IPs... but did you verify that *each of* the balancer's IPs works?  A misconfiguration of a balancer, such as by placing it on a public subnet in one AS and a private subnet or subnet with an incorrect default route table in second AZ would guarantee that it never works when accessed by one of its IP addresses.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot You might be on to the issue here. It appears that it is only working from one of the IPs and not all 3. I guess I just randomly grabbed the one that works? So maybe the problem is that I setup the ALB in a different AZ than the private subnets? Reading through [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/public-load-balancer-private-ec2/) it seems I am supposed to match the AZs between public and private networks. Not sure if I am on the right track or not though. I can share the route table configurations as well if it would help.

Comment: The balancer should be attached *only* to public subnets, where the default route in each subnet's route table is pointing to the igw-xxxx Internet Gateway.  The instances behind the balancer should be on private subnets that are in the same AZs as the public subnets to which the balancer is attached.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot okay, I think that is going to be my issue then. Going to change their AZs to match and will follow up afterwards.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I changed the public / private networks around and removed the private ones from the ALB and that did the trick, so if you want to add it as an answer, I will mark it as the solution. Thanks!